# XPath and html: merge tr-pairs ? (or text() thereof)

Tags: python, xpath

Is this possible? I have a list of `<tr>` elements and the XPath expression `//tr`. Instead of returning/matching each `<tr>` element individually, I want to merge the first with the second, the third with the fourth, etc. Is this possible?

I'm using the `lxml.html` python package for html parsing and xpath evaluation.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer! https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ I'd actually recommend you to do that, instead of editing the question, because it makes it easier to find and apply the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working for text concat():

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import elementpath

doc = ET.HTML("<tr><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>4</td></tr>")

for item in elementpath.select(doc, "//tr[position() mod 2 = 1]/concat(.,' => ',following-sibling::tr[1])"):
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
1 => 2
3 => 4
```

Still looking for a solution that merges two `<td>`'s into a single `<tr>` and returns an array of those `<tr>`'s with half the original length.

Answer (score 0):

You can get two lists (odd and even) of elements with XPath expressions:

```
//tr[position() mod 2=1] # returns 1st, 3rd, 5th... tr node
//tr[position() mod 2=0] # returns 2nd, 4th...
```

and then (let say we got two lists of strings: `even` and `odd`) join each pair with Python code

```
for i, j in zip(even, odd):
    print(' '.join([i, j]))
```

This should return joined with space tr values of 1 + 2, 3 + 4, 5 + 6...

Comment: Can't use python for that. Maybe I should look into XSLT.